# How to recover an incomplete MOV file made in Photobooth?

Tags: video, data-recovery, photo-booth, mov

I was recording a very important video with Photobooth. Unfortunately, near the end, it ran out of file space. So it was recording, and there is a 1 TB MOVE file there, but the end is missing. This means the file will not play at all. Is there any method I can use to recover the file, at least the minutes recorded up until the file space ran out?

Comment: I have had success opening incomplete movie files in VLC. It may either repair the file or you may be able to stream the good parts of the file to a new movie file on disk.

Comment: I installed VLC, but it believes the file has a duration of "0 minutes" and won't play. The file does have use more than 1 TB of space though.

Comment: My only other suggestion is Handbrake. Which is actually a video transcoder and **might* be able to fix it. Other than that I am out of ideas.